# Is Hearbeat a good option for check client is alive in a not long running wcf service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a wcf service (PerSession) that wrap libvlc for start and stop video streaming from ip camera. A client select the channel it want to receive streaming (unicast, multicast) and in the service side i start the streaming with libvlc (nVLC), this is not a long running task, it start the transmission and return the mrl quickly. Now i need a time based check if client is alive, for stop the transmission if client is not alive to save resources (cpu in the transcoding process, and bandwith in the streaming transmission). In my research i found the "hearbeat" concept but it is bounded to long running process in every explanation. My quests are:

1. Is hearbeat the solution to my problem or a time based mandatory ping from client to service is better in my situation.
2. Is mandatory a dual channel connection in my situation or with one-way i solve.

Answer (score 1):

What binding are you using ?If you are not using webHttpBinding you could just registry for Closed event of IClientChannel and wcf handled everything for you. Your service contract will be like below.

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]

public partial class MyServiceContract :IMyServiceContract,IChannelInitializer, IContractBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.ChannelDispatcher.ChannelInitializers.Add(this);
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {

    }

    public void Initialize(System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {

       channel.Closed += new EventHandler(client_Disconnected);
    }

    private void client_Disconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       IClientChannel channel =(IClientChannel)sender;

       // free your resources here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, i use multiples binding (net.tcp, wsHttp), i am very new with WCF machinery and don't understand the workflow of method you propose, but is a beginning. The channel Closed event work even if client is abruptly disconnected?

Comment: @OmarSalasGarcia , the channel Closed event work even if client is abruptly disconnected such as power and network failure. The o point that you have to notice that there is a delay time before you know the client disconnected like heart beat. The delay time can be configure in your with "App.config" file. The "inactivityTimeout" properties  is of "reliableSession" tag is the delay time which the wcf service will wait until Closed event is trigger

Comment: @OmarSalasGarcia for wsHttp binding you will need to use heart beat

Comment: @OmarSalasGarcia I don't know if you will need to handle cases like this , I will put it here just in case.Let assume the client as "c1" , and we set the inactivity timeout to 5 minute. The "c1" close the program therefore after 5 minute it trigger the close event for "c1". The "c1" reconnect again in 3 minute. Even though it is the same client (c1) , the wcf doesn't know that because of different session therefore the closed event for previous "c1" will be trigger.You will need to create a counter-based solution to handle it. I can help you if you have problem with counter-based solution.